# Delete part of name | PHP

Tags: php

I want to delete part of name. Users enter the name. Part that I want to delete is part after _. I made code which will find _ in name. Now I have problem, function `strdel`(PAWN) doesn't exist, `str_replace` won't help because it doesn't work as `strdel`. If is _ 6th sign in string, I want to delete all signs after 6th(including 6th). Here's doc for `strdel` -> https://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Strdel
Does PHP have similar function like `strdel`(with `start` and `end` parameter)?

Code: `$_hsync_ime__ = strpos($_hsync_ime, "_");`

Comment: You already have many useful answers, I personally would make use of the explode method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo strstr($string, '_', true);
```

We set the parameter `before_needle` to true to return the part BEFORE `_`

http://php.net/manual/de/function.strstr.php

Comment: this 1 is faster than all the other answers here using explode :)

Comment: This Works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this :

```
<?php
// $name = 'lorem_ipsum123456'
$nameTab = explode('_', $name);
echo $nameTab[0] // lorem
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use explode

```
$test = "abc_xyz";
$new = explode("_",$test)[0];
```

Check this: https://eval.in/588659